# Парсинг ленты новостей VK, FB.

Tags: vkontakte-api, facebook-api

Возможно ли парсить ленту новостей (feed) ВК и FB пользователя используя API?
Быстрый ресерч ничего не дал, хотелось бы для начала спросить, чтобы углубляться в поиски далее. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ВКонтакте можно методом [newsfeed.get()](https://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=newsfeed.get), в FB наверняка тоже можно — для мобильных клиентов и пр. примочек это часто требуется.

Comment: Это лента стены юзера, а мне нужно лента новостей. Вконтакте она стоит главной страницей (vk.com/feed)

Comment: Исправил ответ на newsfeed.get()

Comment: А это, вроде как, на обычном сайте не заработает. Или нет?

Comment: Не вижу причин, почему бы не заработать. Только надо будет снабдить его токеном хотя бы единственного установившего его пользователя - админа приложения, например. Тогда приложению будут видны или не видны те же новости на чужих стенах, что и этому пользователю.

Comment: Нужно получать кокретный фид для каждого вошедшего, так должно заработать?

Comment: Для этой ф-ии приложение должно иметь права с маской "2". Значит, либо каждого вошедшего просить установить его себе и действовать от его лица, либо однажды админу получить вечный токен, и от лица админа "смотреть" фид каждого из пользователей. Разумеется, во 2-м варианте фиды буду дырявыми - без скрытых от админа постов.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.